# relationship between peak value and rms

Tags: matlab, signals

suppose that we have  following signal:

Compute the RMS level of a 100-Hz sinusoid sampled at 1 kHz.

```
t = 0:0.001:1-0.001;
X = cos(2*pi*100*t);
```

it's spectrum is

```
plot(periodogram(X));
```

[image]

now if i want to  to calculate magnitude of peak,i  know that there is some relationship between  root  mean square(RMS) and amplitude for sinusoidal models,form this site

http://www.indiana.edu/~emusic/acoustics/amplitude.htm

Example: The rms of a sine wave with a hypothetical peak-to peak value of –1 to 1 will be 0.707. This can be used to extrapolate that any rms amplitude = 0.707 x peak amplitude. Peak amplitude = 1.414 x rms amplitude.

i can calculate

```
 y=rms(X);
```

si does it means that  peak ampltide=1.414*rms(X)?in this case i have got

```
y*1.414

ans =

    0.9998
```

but why does it gives me  so small number?peak is more then   45 from picture,please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are confusing the frequency and time domains - your plot is in the frequency domain while RMS describes the Root Mean Square value of the time domain signal.

If you plot the generated cosine signal in the time domain, you will see a cosine with an amplitude of 1. In the frequency domain (seen in your figure), the x-axis is the frequency and the y-axis is the signal energy. Thus the peak would be higher for a signal measured over longer time.

Regarding the calculation you make in the end:

```
y=rms(X);
```

Gives you the rms value of the signal (in the time domain) as y. Multiplying y by 1.414 gives you the signal amplitude (with a decimal error for rounding sqrt(2) ).

So in short I think your confusion comes from the plot being in the frequency domain and the RMS value being in the time domain. Thus the peak of the plot is not related to the RMS value.

Comment: Yes the amplitude is in the time domain, and can be seen directly from: plot(t,X)